# Build separated Kotlin modules with Gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm building a kotlin multiplaform project and I would like to setup a particular build with gradle but I'm having a hard time understanding all the documentations.
Below is my build.gradle.kts file :

```
val ktorVersion = "2.3.0"


plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
    application // gradle plugin to run JVM part
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.8.10"
}

group = "com.tessanix"
version = "0.0.1"

application {
    //mainClass.set("io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain")//
    mainClass.set("ApplicationKt")
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

kotlin {
    jvm { jvmToolchain(18) }
    js(IR) {
        browser {
            binaries.executable()
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.runtime)
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.0")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-host-common-jvm:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-cors:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-compression:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }

        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.web.core)
                implementation(compose.runtime)
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-js:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
        
        val jsTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-js"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see my project is separated in 3 main modules : jsMain, jvmMain and commonMain.
I would like to first build the jsMain module and copy the output ressources (html, css and javascript files) directly into the jvmMain resources folder. Finally I want to build the jvmMain module and run it. I know it is possible to do this kind a things with gradle tasks, is there any gradle expert here ?

Comment: I don't have a working example, but I think you shouldn't add such dependency between tasks. If your JVM application uses artifacts of JS application then I suggest creating two separate Gradle modules.

Comment: Do you mean creating a build.gradle.kts for each jsMain, jvmMain and commonMain ?